# Subclass UIViewController for 10 different scenes but using single storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I have a single ViewControllerA that contains 90% of functionality needed by 9 more ViewControllers. I am using single storyboard for all 10 ViewControllers in which I use segue for transitioning from one ViewController or scene to the next.

**ViewControllerA**

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "showViewControllerB" {
         NSLog("Transition to scene B")
         _ = segue.destination as! ViewControllerB
     }
   }
}
```

**ViewControllerB**

The second view controller, ViewControllerB  is a subclass of ViewControllerA as shown below. This means I get all functionality from ViewControllerA in ViewControllerB. At this step I still use same storyboard scene and use segue for transition to ViewControllerC which also will be subclass of ViewControllerA.

```
    class ViewControllerB: ViewControllerA {
      override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "showViewControllerC" {
         NSLog("Transition to scene C")
         _ = segue.destination as! ViewControllerC
     }
   }
}
```

Is this kind of subclassing approach valid? If not what is the best way to handle this kind of subclassing between 10 different ViewControllers where first ViewController has 90% of information needed by the rest of ViewControllers used by a single storyboard?

Comment: Yes, that's a perfectly valid (and preferable) way to do this.

Comment: Am I properly dismissing during this transition between viewControllers? If I add image programmatically in ViewControllerA but want to use that same function in ViewControllerB to add different image, how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: For me i prefer separate that view controller to make it standalone, including it's view, that way enable for easier understand and easier change later, so making both `ViewControllerA ` and `ViewControllerB ` subclassed another `Viewcontroller`, by then, code from `ViewControllerB` will not point back to `ViewControllerA` anymore

Comment: The best way to implement this is use override as originally posted. Hopefully others with no knowledge about this can benefit from this question about view controllers subclassing. Thanks.